# Sort Posts by Multiple Meta Values

Tags: query-posts, sort, meta-query

1) Custom Post Type named "Buying_Locations"

2) Each Post has three meta values of: State, City, Store Name

**QUESTION:**
 How can you show a list of these posts sorted alphabetically by State, then City and then the Store Name? For example...

**STATE 1**

- CITY 1

  - STORE NAME
  - STORE NAME
  - STORE NAME
- CITY 2

  - STORE NAME
  - STORE NAME
  - STORE NAME
- CITY 3

  - STORE NAME
  - STORE NAME
  - STORE NAME

**STATE 2**

- CITY 1

  - STORE NAME
  - STORE NAME
  - STORE NAME
- CITY 2

  - STORE NAME
  - STORE NAME
  - STORE NAME

**STATE 3**

- CITY 1

  - STORE NAME
  - STORE NAME
- CITY 2

  - STORE NAME
  - STORE NAME
  - STORE NAME
- CITY 3

  - STORE NAME

I've gotten a little further with this:

```
$mypost = array( 
'post_type' => 'buy_locations', 
'posts_per_page' => -1, 
'meta_key' => 'store_city', 
'orderby' => 'meta_value title', 
'order' => 'ASC' 
); 
$loop = new WP_Query( $mypost );
```

Just need to figure out how to sort by the State first, then the city, then title.

Not sure how to add the extra "meta_key" value.

How do I add the 3rd sorting request?

```
$mypost = array( 
    'post_type' => 'buy_locations', 
    'posts_per_page' => -1, 
    'meta_key1' => 'store_state', 
    'meta_key2' => 'store_city', 
    'orderby' => 'meta_value1 meta_value2 title', 
    'order' => 'ASC' 
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

Haven't checked this, but a quick look at the Codex says that your query should just include
`'Orderby' => 'state city name'`

Comment: I edited the code example above. Got a little further along with it. Maybe you have some insight on how to add the extra 'meta_key'? Please see above. Thanks much.

Comment: Apologies - it was late and my brain wasn't compeltely in gear so I failed to notice the fact that I was typing 3 meta_key's!

I've done a little more searching and I think you're beyond the capabilities of the wordpress core.

I think the answer is in filtering the OrderBy element: `add_filter('posts_orderby', 'edit_posts_orderby');`, however my SQL is pretty poor!

Sorry I couldn't help more, I would be interested if you get a solution though

Comment: I found this (http://wordpress.mcdspot.com/2012/10/24/sort-posts-on-multiple-custom-fields/) and I'm right there with adjusting it to suit my needs. The last thing to figure out is how to get the final 3rd sorting on the Post's Title.

Answer (score 0):

Since I couldn't find the way to grab the custom post's title and add it to the sorting/ordering by meta_key, I edited my custom post type to include a hidden field that grabs the title of the post and sets it as a custom meta value when the user adds a new custom post. So, in my custom post type plugin, I have:

```
<input type="hidden" name="buy_location_name" value="<?php echo get_the_title($buy_location->ID); ?>" />

if ( isset( $_POST['buy_location_name'] ) && $_POST['buy_location_name'] != '' ) 
 { update_post_meta( $buy_location_id, 'location_name', get_the_title($buy_location_id) ); }
```

And then on the frontend page that posts the results sorted by State, City and finally Store name, I use the example code found in this URL: http://wordpress.mcdspot.com/2012/10/24/sort-posts-on-multiple-custom-fields/

My code starts like so...

```
$meta_keys = array('store_state','store_city','location_name');
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'buy_locations',
    'meta_key' => $meta_keys[0],
    'orderby' => 'meta_value',
    'posts_per_page' => -1);
$my_query = new WP_Query($args);
```

And then later on, ends with...

```
usort($my_query->posts, 'sort_3_keys');
while ( $my_query->have_posts() ) : $my_query->the_post();
$id = $post->ID;
$storestate = $id_array[$id][$meta_keys[0]];
$storecity = $id_array[$id][$meta_keys[1]];
$storename = $id_array[$id][$meta_keys[2]];
echo "$storestate | $storecity | $storename <br />";
endwhile;
```

In summary, the cat who developed this code (http://wordpress.mcdspot.com/2012/10/24/sort-posts-on-multiple-custom-fields/), is one bad muthah and I'm grateful for his work and for him sharing it. This has helped me achieve the results I needed. Cheers.